# Run two tasks/scripts that both "hog the terminal"

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, json-server

I'm trying to setup [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#video) and browser-sync to work as npm script. I tried to run them seperately and that works fine, however, at the end, both json-server and browser-sync does "hog the terminal" for their cycle. I did put the `gulp serve` first and it triggers that but does not continue to `json-server`. Any ideas how to solve to run both commands at one npm script?

I tried both this

1:

```
"dev": "json-server --watch db.json --port 4200" && gulp serve"
```

2:

```
"predev": "json-server --watch db.json --port 4200",
"dev": "gulp serve"
```

runnit it `npm run dev`